# Android layout custom round progressbar with slices and range

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I am trying to make this mockup real:

[image: mockup]

What I did is:

[image]

but I can't divide the progressbar into slices and I can't create the big slice in the middle which rapresents the range. The slices should be at a certain value and the big one has a start and a finish value for range. Any help?

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="false">

        <solid android:color="@color/lightGrey" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="true">

            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:startColor="@color/grey"
                android:endColor="@color/red"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```